# Citrix VPN and local traffic privacy

Tags: vpn, citrix

I'm connecting to a Citrix Access Gateway using Citrix Receiver. Can my company see local network traffic (pages I visit on my home computer, etc.)?  I've checked the IP on my local connection and it is my ISP and not the same as my work IP.

I'm not even sure if this is possible with Citrix under any circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the CAG for VPN, all traffic will pass through the Citrix, tunnel and will use your work's proxies etc. This is what makes the connection secure and mitigates for data leakage.